# Application not getting installed in Silent Mode

Tags: windows, batch-file, installation, silent-installer

I was given a task to install application silently on a machine. I had NO clue as how to achieve this. After spending some time, I felt it can be done through batch files and I started to learn creating batch files. I learnt how to copy file in different locations and other basic stuff.

As a practice I am trying to install `7zip.msi` silently. I create a batch file with code

```
start C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\7zip.msi /quiet
```

I ran the batch file from the command prompt and it asked me to confirm with below window

[image]

I clicked run. And then nothing happens. I felt it is installing in the background (silently) but I am not sure if the installation is finished. And don't know how to get the status of installation. I waited for 20 min and saw in installed programs but my application was not there. I restarted and again nothing was in installed programs.

I have even tried with following code but ended up with same result

```
start C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\7zip.msi <Silent>
```

Can any one help me on this?? I know there are lot of articles out there, but I have reached there with there help only. I could not figure out whats happening.

And will same batch will work with an `.exe` file also? Thanks.

Comment: If you leave out the "start" (or make it "start /wait") the batch file will wait for the installer to exit.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
msiexec.exe /i "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\7zip.msi" /quiet
```

I took this from [here](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/msiexec.html), which has documentation and examples on msi switches.

You can't do the same with exe's, unless they have the same switches built into them by the developer.

Comment: +1....and thanks for help. But how can I know what switched or properties that exe exposes??

Comment: Thanks, you would need to check the docs for any switches it may have, it really depends on what it is. Just check the website you got it from and see if there is any docs for it, if not then I would presume it doesn't have any.